# How can I fix the 0 output I'm getting in this program?

Tags: python

I might have made this program more complicated than it needs to be. But I'm having to do this with restrictions due to it being part of a learning course. For the most part, this seems to work, though I seem to always get a 0 output with the "largest" integer. Sometimes when putting in a similar sequence of numbers, like 555, I'll also see 5,0,0 return.

**I'm just wanting to have the program pull of arranging a sequence of numbers.** I'm sure this is possible in a wide variety of ways, but I want to see if this way I have is optimizable. Thank you so much for the input!

```
first = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
second = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
third = int(input("Enter the third number: ")) 
small = 0
middle = 0
large = 0 
if first < third and first < second:
    small = first
elif second < third and second < first:
    small = second
else:
    small = third 
if first < second and first < third:
    middle = first
    if second > first and second < third:
        middle = second
    else:
        middle = third 
elif first > second and first > third:
    large = first
    if second > first and second > third:
        large = second
    else:
        large = third
print("The numbers in accending order are: ", small, middle, large)
```

Comment: Your second `if` statement is the same as your first `if` statement. Is that intentional? You can simply debug this yourself by printing something unique after eah branch in the code. Or use a debugger.

Comment: FWIW, you can condense all that to `print(sorted((first, second, third)))`…

Comment: Note that the question is `[...] I want to see if this way I have is optimizable`

Comment: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). This will help as well [pythontutor.com](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)

Comment: You probably should just change all your operators to the equal alternatives: `<` to `<=`

Comment: Having another look at your code. Something is fundamentally wrong. You will always assign **EITHER** `middle` or `large` as they are part of `if/elif`. So you will never assign both. That doesn't sound like what you want

Comment: Can the solution use a different set of if statements to find small, medium and large or should it only tweak (i.e. fix) your current if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that none of the `if` statements are actually being executed, so the `small, middle, large` values don't change (they remain at their initial value, `0`).

The reason for this is that you are checking if the values are LARGER or SMALLER than each other, when they are actually EQUAL (returning `False`). And since no `if` statements are executed, only `else` statements are executed (hence the `5` in  `5,0,0`).

Try doing something like this instead:

```
# NOTE: the change is the <= and >= rather than simply < or >
if first <= third and first <= second:
    small = first
elif second <= third and second <= first:
    small = second
else:
    small = third

# NOTE: I also made a few changes to the code below

# Reason: Earlier middle wasn't being set at all if first >= second and first <= third was
# false, a similar reason goes for the large value not changing

# I also changed the definition of middle to include the fact that first can be more than
# second and less than third or vice versa (more than third and less than second)
if (first >= second and first <= third) or (first <= second and first >= third):
    middle = first
elif (second >= first and second <= third) or (second <= first and second >= third):
    middle = second
else:
    middle = third 
if first >= second and first >= third:
    large = first
elif second >= first and second >= third:
    large = second
else:
    large = third
```

Hope this helped :D

Comment: I've made this more complicated than it needs to be, considering the restrictions and my basic understanding. The input is helping to a degree so far.

Comment: Ok, I _think_ I've fixed it now, sorry for any inconvenience I may have caused

Comment: Wouldn't this be much simpler if once you know, for instance, that `small = first`, `middle` is the lesser of `second` and `third` and so one.

Answer (score 0):

The first part where you assign `small` is correct except that you're only checking for `<` and `>`, if two or more numbers are equal this won't be working. So I changed the comparison operators to `<=` and `>=` and I rewrote the two other parts in the same style. So it now looks like this (which is working):

```
first = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
second = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
third = int(input("Enter the third number: "))
small = 0
middle = 0
large = 0

if first <= third and first <= second:
    small = first
elif second <= third and second <= first:
    small = second
else:
    small = third

if first <= second and first >= third or first >= second and first <= third:
    middle = first
elif second >= first and second <= third or second <= first and second >= third:
    middle = second
else:
    middle = third

if first >= second and first >= third:
    large = first
elif second >= first and second >= third:
    large = second
else:
    large = third
print("The numbers in accending order are: ", small, middle, large)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code as-is tries to find each of the smallest, middle and largest without regard for previous steps. It would be much simpler to remember previous checks, like this for instance:

```py
first = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
second = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
third = int(input("Enter the third number: ")) 
small = 0
middle = 0
large = 0 
if first <= third and first <= second:
  if second <= third:
    small, middle, large = first, second, third
  else:
    small, middle, large = first, third, second
elif second <= third and second <= first:
  if first <= third:
    small, middle, large = second, first, third
  else:
    small, middle, large = second, third, first
elif third <= second and third <= first:
  if first <= second:
    small, middle, large = third, first, second
  else:
    small, middle, large = third, second, first

print("The numbers in accending order are: ", small, middle, large)
```